# Js script keeps executing onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code below keeps adding text boxes. I want it just to add what ever the first choice is then stop. If you press one, then two, it adds  two more, then keeps doing it if you select more.

```js
$(function(){
  $('select').on('change', function() {
  i = 1
  var y = parseInt(this.value) + 1
   while (i != y)

   {
    $("#boxes").append('<input type="text" name="ticket_'+ i + '_name" placeholder="Ticket ' + i +' Type">');
    $("#boxes").append('<input type="text" name="ticket_'+ i + '_price" placeholder="Ticket ' + i +' Price">');
    $("#boxes").append('<input type="text" name="ticket_'+ i + '_quantity" placeholder="Ticket ' + i +' Quantity">');
    $("#boxes").append('<p></p>');
    i = i + 1

    if (i == y){
     return false
    }
   }
    
  })
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="add.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <select id="droplist">
     <option>Select</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>


    <form id="boxes">
  <input type='hidden' name='eventname' value='$eventname '>
    </form>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.append()` function will add whatever you've got in it to the end of the element you've selected (this is the definition of append). So your code says "Whenever an select option is picked, tack these on the end".

However, it sounds like you don't want to add the new ones on the end, you want them to be the only ones, which means getting rid of the first ones beforehand.

Above the `while(i != y)` line, add `$('#boxes').empty();`. [This](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) will remove all the elements currently inside #boxes, giving you an empty field to put your new round of fields in.

Also, side note, instead of that `while` and `if` and `return false` business, you might be better served using a `for` loop.

Comment: Hello :) almost works! I still need two boxes when 2 is selected with two ticket types, then three when 3 is selected and so on. This eliminates all and just gives one.

Comment: Oh yep, because it's inside the loop. My bad, move the empty() line to before the while loop, instead of being inside. I'll update the answer to reflect.